# Why when installing cron along with playwright,errors occur in the absence of the playwright module

Tags: parsing, parse-platform, playwright, playwright-python

The launch takes place on a VPS. So, if you run the code without cron-a, then everything is OK, the sites are parsed. When I add cron, everything flies into a heap with errors. Here is what my log gives me

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/apars/nobr.py", line 39, in <module>
    povtor()
File "/apars/nobr.py", line 9, in povtor
    x = obr_cnt()   
File "/apars/obrzka_count.py", line 8, in obr_cnt
    id_mobile = parser()
File "/apars/parser_new.py", line 4, in parser
    from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playwright'`
```

Although everything is installed in ubuntu and this is what pip3 list shows...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFkox.png)

Removing the entry about the program launch from the cron, everything falls into place. Perhaps someone has come across the same problem and can help me.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` is probably being run as a different user and so it has a different `site-packages` directory where it pulls installed modules from.

You can either install playwright for root user, or schedule the cron job to be run by your current user.  The second is probably the better option.

The other possibility is that you are running your tests in a virtual environment that `cron` doesn't have access to. Either way the solution is to make sure that `cron` has access to all of the python modules needed to run the script.

To schedule a job for a specific user use `crontab -u username -e`

Comment: Helped adding and updating packages both in vevn and in root. Thank u

Comment: @Nik Sounds like your problem was solved, which is great! (Or maybe clarify if not) If you’re indicating that this answer solved your problem, please accept it. Or if it needed a bit more information you figured out, perhaps edit and accept it, or if you came to a different solution add your own answer. That way the question has an accepted answer and people know at first glance that it is solved. Thanks!